# Adding new custom opcode to solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, opcode

I have a problem with adding new opcode to solidity. I'm using solc (on C++) and geth(ethereum on Go). I want to add new opcode, that takes `address payable, uint256, uint256, bytes memory` and returns `bytes memory`. So I have a problem with return value.

Some peaces of code below, I will skip some files, to make question shorter.

1. Solc

- `libsolidity/codegen/ExpressionCompiler.cpp`

```
// ExpressionCompiler::visit(FunctionCall const& _functionCall)
case FunctionType::Kind::MyOpcode:
{
    acceptAndConvert(*arguments[0], *function.parameterTypes()[0], true);
    acceptAndConvert(*arguments[1], *function.parameterTypes()[1], true);
    acceptAndConvert(*arguments[2], *function.parameterTypes()[2], true);
    arguments[3]->accept(*this);
    utils().fetchFreeMemoryPointer();
    utils().packedEncode(
        {arguments[3]->annotation().type},
        {TypeProvider::array(DataLocation::Memory, true)}
    );
    utils().toSizeAfterFreeMemoryPointer();

    m_context << Instruction::MYOPCODE;
}
```

- `libsolidity/analysis/GlobalContext.cpp`

```
// inline vector<shared_ptr<MagicVariableDeclaration const>> constructMagicVariables()
magicVarDecl("myopcode", TypeProvider::function(strings{"address payable", "uint256", "uint256", "bytes memory"}, strings{"bytes memory"}, FunctionType::Kind::MyOpcode, false, StateMutability::Payable)),
```

- libevmasm/Instruction.cpp

```
// static std::map<Instruction, InstructionInfo> const c_instructionInfo =
{ Instruction::MYOPCODE,       { "MYOPCODE",          0, 5, 1, true, Tier::Base } }
```

2. Geth

- core/vm/jump_table.go

```
// func newFrontierInstructionSet() JumpTable {
CALLACTOR: {
    execute:    opMyOpCode,
    dynamicGas: gasCallActor,
    minStack:   minStack(5, 1),
    maxStack:   maxStack(5, 1),
    memorySize: memoryReturn,
    writes:     true,
    returns:    true,
},
```

- core/vm/instructions.go

```
func opMyOpcode(pc *uint64, interpreter *EVMInterpreter, callContext *callCtx) ([]byte, error) {
    inoffset, insize := callContext.stack.pop(), callContext.stack.pop()
    params := callContext.memory.GetPtr(int64(inoffset.Uint64()), int64(insize.Uint64()))

    secondValue := callContext.stack.pop()

    firstValue := callContext.stack.pop()

    addr := callContext.stack.pop()

    // ... Do smth with input ...

    outoffset := inoffset.Uint64() + insize.Uint64()

    callContext.memory.Set(outoffset, 1, []byte{0x2})
    tmp := make([]byte, 1)
    tmp[0] = 0x98
    callContext.memory.Set(outoffset + 1, 1, tmp)

    callContext.stack.push(uint256.NewInt().SetUint64(outoffset))

    return tmp, nil
}
```

3. Smart contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0; // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3
contract test {
    event ReturnValue(address payable _from, bytes data);
    function f() public returns(bytes memory){
        address payable addr1 = payable(msg.sender);
        bytes memory params = new bytes(2);
        params[0] = 0x21;
        params[1] = 0x22;
        bytes memory result = myopcode(addr1, 0x11, 0x12, params);
        emit ReturnValue(addr1, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I run that code I get `invalid jump destination`. So, what I need to do, to get my code work correctly?

Comment: Nobody probably knows answer you to question, because it is so niche and only handful of people in the whole world ever have thought about it. Better ot ask from Geth developers directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it certainly looks stupid, but this case is already provided by the developers. All you need is `utils().returnDataToArray()`.